# Result from oracle in python

Tags: python, oracle

I make a query to oracle database as:

```
SQL="SELECT listagg(project_symbol,', ') within group (order by project_symbol) from Objects where project_symbol like '1%/W/2017'"
cursor.execute(SQL)
for x in cursor:
    print x
```

and the result is:

```
('\x001\x00/\x00W\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x007, \x001\x00/\x00W\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x007)
```

I expected something like eg:

```
('123/W/2017','134/W/2017')
```

how to correctly display the query result?

Answer (score 0):

Try `print [field.decode('utf-8') for field in x]`, should help.

Apparently cx_Oracle gives you text data in whatever encoding `NLS_LANG` is set to, without converting them to Unicode for you.

Comment: When I add ".decode('UTF-8') I get "'tuple' object has no attribute decode"

Comment: I try for x in cursor:
    for y in x:
        print y.decode('utf-8'). But the result was None

Comment: Ah, yes, you need something like `x[0].decode(...)`, because `x` is a tuple! Updating the answer.